# Thrift API method 'authenticate' not found in WSO2 identity server 5.0

Tags: java, authentication, wso2, thrift

I met a problem in WSO2 identity server 5.0 windows version.
I download the version from wso2.com and unzip, start the server by running `$IS_HOME/bin/wso2server.bat`.
Then I write a thrift java client, calling the authenticate API which is listed in

```
$IS_HOME/repository/components/plugins/org.wso2.carbon.identity.thrift.authentication_4.2.1.jar/authenticator.thrift
```

The calling failed, the error message was:

```
org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Invalid method name: 'authenticate'
            at org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:108)
            at org.wso2.carbon.identity.thrift.authentication.AuthenticatorService$Client.recv_authenticate(AuthenticatorService.java:95)
            at org.wso2.carbon.identity.thrift.authentication.AuthenticatorService$Client.authenticate(AuthenticatorService.java:77)
            at com.mine.client.WSO2Client.main(WSO2Client.java:40)
```

It seems that the server has received the request, but it can't find the 'authenticate' method.
But the method is listed in authenticator.thrift.
Is there anyone can help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are trying to use thrift for calling the Entitlement service.  If you can find a java client from [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/xacml/pep/thrift/). Please go through it, it may help you to resolve the issue.